# iPhone 3G w/o SIM messaging app

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, sim

I would like to use our jailbroke iPhone 3G with NO SIM. Is it possible to use the built in messaging app that Apple supplies on this iPhone wit no SIM?

Is this possible to do or do I need to use one of the other free text apps?  If it's possible could some one please post the instructions.

Why is it that our iPad is able to use the messaging app but I can't with the NO SIM 3G?

Edit:
I previously thought I had the iPhone 3GS. I recently edited because I found I have the iPhone 3G (not S)

Answer (score 1):

Your iPhone 3G isn't eligible to upgrade to iOS 5+ which use iMessage, as a supplementary (or primary) means of messaging, and which does not require use of SMS (cellular transfer).

As a result, you will need to rely on a 3rd party app (that supports iOS 4) to do your messaging. A Google search revealed that there are still a number of texting apps that support iOS 4.3 (which your phone should support) such as:  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textplus-free-text-group-texting/id314487667?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

Comment: So what is the app that is currently on this iPhone?  It looks like the same app that is on our iPad and iPod touch.

Comment: @Bud, *"iMessage"* is the "texting" service that is free with iOS 5+ devices. This allows you to "iMessage" other "iMessage" user. *"Messages"* is the name of the app on the iPhone.

Comment: OK.  Still very new to this.

Comment: Here's how new I am to this.  Turns out the phone I have is only a 3G

Comment: @bud, that certainly changes the problem. I will edit (completely) my answer to reflect the answer to your situation better.

Answer (score 0):

Pairing Messages and [Google Voice](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-voice/id318698524?mt=8) on that phone could really be a great combo if youre just using it as a texting tool. I would grab a free wifi finder app too to maximize your range.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 3g can only be updated as far as iOS 4.2.1. Therefore you cannot use iMessage. I would say get [Google Voice](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-voice/id318698524?mt=8) and try to emulate it that way, unfortunately you wont be able to send pic and video messages.